# Should I treat my sill plate and rim joist before insulating?

Tags: wood, insulation, basement, waterproofing, basement-refinishing

Original 1943 construction with an unfinished full-height basement that I'm beginning the process of converting to habitable space. There are various signs of historical water damage on some of the wood. The space has been heated and dehumidified for the last two years with no sign of continuing water incursion or any pest issues. Soil is well below the sill outside.

My plan is to glue and seal rigid XPS foam into the bays created by the framing so that the cavity is available behind the future wall to contain another refrigerant lineset and some more electrical.

Is it a good idea to treat the wood before installing foam over it? [PenaShield](https://nisuscorp.com/product/penashield) seems to be the best option for indoor use, but I'm not sure if it would be overkill or have some unintended consequence.

Climate zone is 4C.

[image]

[image]